# Tomcat directly serve static (css, js) files shared by multiple applications

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat6

I'm using the ExtJS framework which has a bulk of `js` and `css` files that are used for all apps. I intend to share these between a number of web applications (different `war` files).

For this reason I would like to serve ExtJS `js` and `css` directly from the web server, in my case `Tomcat6`, which can be used to serve static files, as in [this helpful link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheTomcat/article.html#tomcat_httpserver).

Therefore I put my files under `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/extjs/`. The static files that are directly under that directory are served correctly, e.g. `/extjs/ext.js` correctly serves the file at `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/extjs/ext.js`.

However files in lower-level directories, for example `/extjs/welcome/css/welcome.css`, which should serve the file at `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/extjs/welcome/css/welcome.css`, return a `404`.

**TL/DR**

Tomcat serves static files only at top-level directory. A `404` is returned for files deeper in the hierarchy.

**Config file contents**:

- [server.xml](http://pastebin.com/jZ5ninuF)
- application's [web.xml](http://pastebin.com/y5hpz6dY)

**FIXED - SOLUTION**:

The issue was that I was placing the clause:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/extjs-static-files" path="/extjs"/>
```

within Tomcat's `server.xml` `<Engine>` clause. Once I placed it within the `<Host>` tag it started working. Reading [this doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) was very helpful in identifying what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a RESTful web service that serves some static content stored in a directory outside of Tomcat. The directory is specified by a servlet parameter in web.xml
You could do something similar and just specify an absolute path to the files you need - place them in Tomcat somewhere or wherever road you like. I can post some sample code if you like.
Of course all other files that reference the javascript and CSS would need to change because these files will be at a different URL directory than the web apps that use them. For instance, src="restAppContextName/serve/youJavaScript.js" where serve is a @Path for the REST web service and whatever follows is a @PathParam. To the browser, /serve will be treated like it's a directory, so a relative reference from one js file to another should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got around it in a different way (updated the question with the "solution". +1'ed your answer since it still is valuable feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic setup to give you better understanding of what-is-what:

**server.xml**

```
<Context docBase="appname" path="/appname" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname"/>
```

*docBase* is the application root folder (webapp)

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/res/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

*res* is just the URI distinguisher; useful if you have another one like /* pointing to a smarter servlet.

The *default* servlet serves statics from the root of the application.
Basically, if the file test.js is in the folder js, that corresponds to the project's:

src/main/webapp/js/test.js

It can be now reached by the URL:

http://localhost:8080/**appname**/**res**/js/test.js